# Simplify PostgreSQL query

Tags: sql, postgresql

Is there a way to simplify the next query:

```
SELECT array[1,2,3] && array[1] 
AND array[1,2,3] && array[2,3] 
AND array[1,2,3] && array[5];
```

Which means

```
true if 
[1,2,3] overlaps(includes at least one common element) [1] 
AND [1,2,3] overlaps [2,3] 
AND [1,2,3] overlaps [5]
```

I need to get rid of ANDs

Comment: I think the example is slightly over-simplified, obscuring the real task; I presume the `array[1,2,3]` in the real query is actually a column or calculated value of some sort?

Comment: having an array of  all product properties we need to filter those which have at least one of selected by user. so close to real data is something like ```['green', 'red', 'brown', '20inch', '40 inch'] && ['green'] AND ['green', 'red', 'brown', '20inch', '40 inch'] && ['20 inch']```

Comment: Please can you [edit] your question to include a more complete example, including a clearer indication of which part is user input, and an example of some data you need to match against. See also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query It would also be useful to understand what problem you are having with the current code - is it performance, flexibility, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your comment, if this is for working with a variable number of search criteria mixing `and` and `or`, then would something like this work for you?

The idea is to pass your array of arrays in as json, and use `jsonb` expansion to rows and later aggregation to find rows that overlap all subarrays.

This example has four products with only one that matches the three different criteria in your question.

```
with products (product_id, attributes) as (
  values (1, array[1,2,3]),
         (2, array[1,2,4]),
         (3, array[2,3,4,5]),
         (4, array[1,2,3,4,5])
), search as (
  select t.rn, array_agg(in_el::int) as search_term, max(t.rn) over () as term_count
    from jsonb_array_elements('[[1],[2,3],[5]]'::jsonb) with ordinality as t(el, rn)
         cross join lateral jsonb_array_elements_text(t.el) as i(in_el)
   group by t.rn
)
select p.*, count(*) as term_hits
  from search s
       join products p
         on p.attributes && s.search_term
 group by p.product_id, p.attributes
having count(*) = max(s.term_count);

┌────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ product_id │ attributes  │ term_hits │
├────────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│          4 │ {1,2,3,4,5} │         3 │
└────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment out the `having. . .`  to get a better look at what's going on.

If your real data has you comparing against `text[]`, then this can be rewritten like so:

```
with products (product_id, attributes) as (
  values (1, array['1','2','3']),
         (2, array['1','2','4']),
         (3, array['2','3','4','5']),
         (4, array['1','2','3','4','5'])
), search as (
  select t.rn, t.el as search_term, max(t.rn) over () as term_count
    from jsonb_array_elements('[["1"],["2","3"],["5"]]'::jsonb) with ordinality as t(el, rn)
)
select p.*, count(*) as term_hits
  from search s
       join products p
         on s.search_term ?| p.attributes
 group by p.product_id, p.attributes
having count(*) = max(s.term_count)
;

┌────────────┬─────────────┬───────────┐
│ product_id │ attributes  │ term_hits │
├────────────┼─────────────┼───────────┤
│          4 │ {1,2,3,4,5} │         3 │
└────────────┴─────────────┴───────────┘
(1 row)
```

Comment: You understood the problem correctly, I have something to start with

Answer (score 0):

Too long for comment!  
Saying you need to get rid of the ANDs is basically saying "I need to totally change the logic of this statement."   Because getting rid of them turns AND conditions to OR conditions. So you can convert to nothing but array operators as:

```
select array[1,2,3] && (array[1] || array[2,3] || array[5]);
```

But this gives the exact same results as just changing AND to OR.

```
select array[1,2,3] && array[1] 
    or array[1,2,3] && array[2,3] 
    or array[1,2,3] && array[5];
```

So you need to describe exactly  what your goal is.